# The react UseEffect don't accept the values

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I can't see where the error is here. Why is my `useEffect` not accepting the ´yourTheme`value?

Code:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import allThemes from './index';

const ThemeContext = createContext({});
const lastThemeIndex = allThemes.length - 1;
const ThemeContextProvider = props => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState();
    const [themeName, setThemeName] = useState(allThemes[0].name);

    useEffect(() => {
        const yourTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
        if (yourTheme) {
            const themeIndex = allThemes.findIndex(t => t.name === yourTheme);
            const selectedTheme = allThemes[themeIndex];
            setTheme(selectedTheme);
        } else {
            setTheme(allThemes[0].theme);
        }
    }, [yourTheme]);

    const setThemeType = () => {
        const themeIndex = allThemes.findIndex(t => t.name === themeName);
        const nextTheme = allThemes[themeIndex === lastThemeIndex ? 0 : themeIndex + 1];
        setTheme({ ...nextTheme.theme });
        setThemeName(nextTheme.name);
        persistThemeType(nextTheme.name);
    };

    function persistThemeType(name) {
        localStorage.setItem('theme', name);
    }

    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider
            value={{
                themeName,
                setThemeType,
            }}
        >
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{props.children}</ThemeProvider>
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default ThemeContext;
export { ThemeContextProvider };
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added `yourTheme` into dependency array which is defined inside `useEffect` This should cause undefined error. As far as you're getting the value from localstorage, you can remove `yourTheme` from dependency array to remove the error.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // ...
}, []);
```